# Upload to website from python

Tags: python, file-upload, upload

I need my program (Python) to upload files (large reports) to services like (rapidshare, megaupload or easyshare) and grab the URL the site gives me (to them forward to the user)

What's easiest way ( I think Selenium, but maybe it's overkill) ?

What's the fastest ( can I do it with mechanize? ) ?

How would you do it?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would attack this with [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), even it beeing really heavy, I think the easy aspect of it is worth it.

I would do what you need to do (upload file to service) by hand while on the [FireFox](http://www.mozilla-europe.org/firefox/) plugin [SeleniumIDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) would be recording it. Them, just export as Python and you have your code.

SeleniumIDE:

[image]

Selenium is a bit to slow, but the simplicity I showed you is well worth it (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

You might check first whether the sites in questions have an API meant for this sort of thing. easy-share for example does (the others are blocked to me at the moment, so haven't checked those): http://www.easy-share.com/be/developers.html (and they even have a ready-made python module available)

Comment: Great ideia... too bad it doesnt work (fine) on Windows. (it needs pycurl, witch in turn needs python 2.5... ) But for LInux this is the best solution